# TypeScript Error with Generator

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm getting errors when trying out this TypeScript in VSCode:

```
enum Desg {
    Consultant,
    Engineer
};

interface Employee {
    Name: string;
    Role: Desg;
}

let names: string[] = ['Sunit', 'Duke'];
//Complains about Name property missing
function* getEmp(): Employee {
    for (let n in names) {
        if (n === 0) //Complains here about n being string
            yield { Name: names[n], Role: Desg.Consultant }
        else
            yield { Name: names[n], Role: Desg.Engineer }
    }
}

for (let n of getEmp()) {
    console.log(`${n.Name} is ${n.Role}`);
}
```

Can someone please enlighten...

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/215552).

Answer (score 0):

A `for...in` loop iterates over the enumerable properties (keys) of an object, which are strings. In your case the object is an array, so the keys are the array indices as strings.

You can confirm this by doing:

```
for (let n in names) {
    console.log(n);
    console.log(typeof n);
}
```

You will see:

```
0
string
1
string
```

So TypeScript can't compare the string `n` to the number `0`.

Note that if you did something like:

```
names["key"] = "value";
```

And then iterated the same way, you'd see:

```
0
string
1
string
key
string
```

This begins to demonstrate why people recommend not using `for...in` to iterate over array indices. Check out the link provided by @Mike McCaughan in the comments for more details.